# Como implementar o std::to_string para ponto flutuante?

Tags: string, c++

Essa pergunta pode parecer mais um pedido, mas pesquiso isso há 2 meses e não sei como resolver.  Preciso implementar o `std::to_string` em C++ (**sem headers**) de uma maneira que aceite valores decimais (`float, double`). Qual a maneira mais adequada? Note que **eu estou implementando minha própria `std::string`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você não especificou nenhuma restrição para a implementação, a forma mais simples de fazer que eu imagino seria:

```
std::string to_string(float f) {
    std::ostringstream buffer;
    buffer << f;
    return buffer.str();
}
```

E o mesmo depois para `double` e `long double`.

Também seria válido ter um array de `char` suficientemente grande e usar `sprintf`.

EDIT:

Como indicado nos comentários, é para ser uma implementação no braço. Um algoritmo que eu implementei rapidamente para fazer isso é o seguinte:

```
std::string to_string(double value, unsigned precision=2) {

    const bool negative = value < 0;
    if (negative) {
        value *= -1;
    }

    //Move a casa decimal para a esquerda o quanto for necessário
    for (unsigned i=0; i<precision; ++i) {
        value *= 10;
    }

    //Converte para inteiro e calcula quantos dígitos vai ter
    unsigned long long i_value = value;
    int digits_count = 0;
    for (unsigned long long v=i_value; v!=0; v /= 10) {
        ++digits_count;
    }

    std::string result;
    result.resize(digits_count+1); //+1 para o '.';

    //Converte para string e põe o '.' no lugar necessário
    int prec_counter = precision;
    for (int pos = result.size()-1; pos >= 0; --pos) {

        if (prec_counter == 0) {
            result[pos] = '.';
        }
        else {
            int digit = i_value % 10;
            i_value /= 10;
            result[pos] = '0' + digit;
        }
        --prec_counter;
    }

    //Remove zeros à direita depois do . decimal
    if (precision > 0) {
        while (result.back() == '0') {
            result.pop_back();
        }
        if (result.back() == '.') {
            result.pop_back();
        }
    }

    return (negative ? "-" : "") + result;
}
```

Este é um algoritmo simples e limitado, mas que pode servir de base para algo mais elaborado. Eu não testei muito, e ele não trata casos especiais, como `NAN`. Estou assumindo que a sua `std::string` possui as funções que eu usei.

Comment: Eu posso apenas usar uma "string", preciso usar C++ sem nenhum header.

Comment: Como usar string e ao mesmo tempo não usar nenhum header? Quais são realmente seus requerimentos?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Eu implementei minha propria string.

Comment: Nesse caso é mais complicado. Se você quiser uma representação exata vai ter que estudar a especificação IEEE. 
Mas para algo rápido e simples, eu começaria testando pelos casos especiais (NAN, +/- infinito, etc.).
Depois converteria para inteiro (via cast) e geraria essa parte. 
Finalmente eu iria pegar a parte fracionária (número original - número truncado), multiplicaria por 100, 1000, 10000 (depende da precisão que você queira) e converteria essa parte. 
Obviamente com checagens para não colocar zeros desnecessários à esquerda.

Comment: Muito, muito obrigado! Tive essa ideia do mesmo algoritmo dormindo, mas esqueci :P

Answer (score 5):

Por que não usa algo pronto? O lexical_cast do Boost resolve.

```
using std::string;
using boost::lexical_cast;

int i = 10;    
string x = lexical_cast<string>(i);
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html

Comment: Sua recomendação além de prática mostra que tem excelente desempenho, conforme pode ser visto aqui http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html

Answer (score 2):

A forma mais simples de implementar a função é confiar no `std::stringstream` que usa os operadores do `std::ostream` que já estarão implementados para os tipos padrões e vários dos  customizados. Isso faria a sua função funcionar para a maioria dos tipos. Um exemplo de implementação:

```c++
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
std::string to_string(const T& value) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << value;
    return ss.str();
}
```